# python 2.7 parse string matching only harddrives

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing

I have a string that looks like

```
"sda   8:0    0   8.3T   0 disk   sdb 8:19   0  931.5G   0 disk"
```

I want to parse it with `re` to only grab each and every `sd*` value from it. So for example on the above string it'd parse:

```
sda
sdb
```

How can I accomplish this in python 2.7 with `re` lib?

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far? Was [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://repl.it/N2aH

Here you don't need use raw string, but it's a good practice with regex :

```
import re

print re.findall(r"sd.", "sda   8:0    0   8.3T   0 disk   sdb 8:19   0  931.5G   0 disk")

# To ignore Case : add `flags=re.IGNORECASE`
print re.findall(r"sd.", "sDa   8:0    0   8.3T   0 disk   Sdb 8:19   0  931.5G   0 disk",flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

regex : `sd.` dot character match any character once time.

regex : `sd*` match `s` character following by 0 or more `d` character.

Comment: One question, is it easily possible to make the search for `sd.` to ignore case?

Comment: Use flags=re.IGNORECASE